# Is it possible to publish multiple applications in play store with same API key?

Tags: android, installation

Am developing maps application using map API key (for example:abc)  in this app by marking few places generated "first.apk"

Now by using the same api key, marked few more places without changing the package name generated "second.apk" so is it possible to keep these two apps (which belongs to same functionality) in play store

Really i have the requirement of it please add some healthy suggestions

Comment: Map api key requires package name. so as long as same package is used in all application you can use same key. other wise you need to create  it for all different package names.

Answer (score 0):

With Maps V2, you can tie up to five package name/signing key pairs to a single API key. A common pattern is to use this so that your debug and production signing keys can map to the same Maps V2 API key, so you do not have to change that key as you move from debug to production. Since the Maps V2 key maps to five package/signing key pairs, you could do that debug-plus-production pattern for two apps if you wanted.

That being said:

> Now by using the same api key, marked few more places without changing the package name generated "second.apk" so is it possible to keep these two apps (which belongs to same functionality) in play store

Package names must be unique on the device, and package names must be unique on the Play Store. If the two APKs have the same package name, they are the same APK from the standpoint of the Android ecosytsem.